# Powershell – Insert a Number Before folder Name – Increment

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to Insert a Number Before folder Name – Increment using Powershell.

The path below is where the subfolders reside.

**C:\Users\Chris Hewitt\Documents\Project\Action Log & Project Stuff\2022**

I found the code below online and tried to get it to work with no luck. I'd really appreciate it if someone could provide feedback as to why this is not working. Thanks in advance

---

Code:

```
$BasePath = "C:\Users\Chris Hewitt\Documents\Project\Action Log & Project Stuff\2022"
$Index = 0
$Folds = Get-ChildItem -Path $BasePath -Attributes "D"

ForEach ($Folder in $Folds) {
  
  $Index += 1
  Rename-Item -Path "$($Folder.fullname)" -NewName "$Index.$Folder"

}

"$Index folders were processed."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that `$($Folder.fullname)` returns a full filepath which is invalid to rename something to. You need to hit the `.name` Attribute. For example

```
ForEach ($Folder in $Folds) {

   $Index += 1
   Rename-Item -Path "$($Folder.FullName)" -NewName "$Index.$($folder.name)"
  
 }
$VerbosePreference = "Continue"
Write-Verbose "$index folders were processed"
```